# Python to VB.NET - Check URL With Tor

Tags: python, vb.net

I have the following code written in python. The script uses Tor expert bundle to check links using Tor.

Would it be possible to write this in VB.NET? I am not sure on vb.net capabilities.

```
#Tor Onion links Active Status checking
import os
import requests
import json
import time
import subprocess

class TorActivation:
    def __ini__(self):
        pass

    def StartTor(self):
        subprocess.Popen([f"{os.getcwd()}\\Tor\\tor.exe"])
        time.sleep(10)
        print("Tor Proxy has been started!!")
        print("Starting Process of Checking")

    def proxy_build(self):
        try:
            self.proxies = {
            'http': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050',
            'https': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050'
            }
            print("proxy setup is succefully done")
    
        except:
            print("Tor is not activated please run the program again!!!")
    

    def check(self,onion,save):
        print()
        try:
            data = requests.get(f"http://{onion}",proxies=self.proxies)
            status=data.status_code
        except:
            status=404
        if status==200:
            print(f"{onion} : Active")
            print(f"Status Code : {status}")
        else:
            print(f"{onion} : nonActive")
            print(f"Status Code : {status}")

        if save==True:
            w=open("Status.txt","a")
            if status==200:
                w.write(f"http://{onion} : Active")
            else:
                w.write(f"http://{onion} : nonActive")
            w.close()
        print()
        return 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    run=TorActivation()
    run.StartTor()
    run.proxy_build()
    while True:
        print("1. Single Url Checking")
        print("2. Multiplt Url Checking")
        print("3. Quit")
        option=input("Enter your option: ")
        if str(option)=='1':
            onion=input("Enter the url: ")
            run.check(onion,False)
        elif str(option)=='2':
            filename=input("Enter the txt filename: ")
            f=open(filename, "a")
            f.readlines()
            for x in f:
                x=x.rstrip("\n")
                run.check(x,True)
            f.close()
        elif option=='3':
            break
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review the [tour], what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic], and [ask]. We're not here to write (or translate) code for you.

Comment: I don't want it wrote. I am asking if it's possible. Please re read the question again

Comment: Is that really what you want to know? To have somebody say "yes" or "no"? I doubt it.

Comment: Yes, exactly as the question states

Comment: [Still off-topic](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/197871). We're not here to read the entire code and determine if it can be written in another language (which effectively requires us to write that code in our minds). Yes, it is possible. Python and VB.NET are both Turing-complete, after all. But this isn't a very useful thing to know. I can say it without knowing any VB.NET or even reading the code you shared above.

Comment: Great, thanks. That's all I wanted to know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question; yes, you can (easily) do that in VB.Net.

Comment: [Please don't answer off-topic questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/354577)